# Can a women take tablets not to get pregnant

Tags: sex, sexuality

Me and my wife would like to have sex but not get pregnant so can she take tablets to not get pregnant or is it haram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is allowed, muslims in the prophet time used to practice pulling out and thete is no problems with it so most schoolers agree that it is allowed